# How to get all non-false values in JPA Query?

Tags: jpa

```
select c.status from Table c where c.id = 13513 and status != false;

true
true
```

But not get null value. I want to get this like value and haw to get?

```
true
true
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much to go on with the context you gave, but try this:

```
select c.status from Table c where c.id = 13513 and (status != false or status is null);
```

If that doesn't work, please post your table schema and, preferably, a data representation that contains the "null" you're looking for.

Comment: looks close, added some parentheses